# Missing pthreadGC2.dll

Tags: c++, dll, pthreads

Hi I'm trying to do a pthread assignment from class but when I run the code, it says [image]

I looked up how to reinstall it but it went to this fishy looking site.

Any ideas how to solve this or even run the program without it?

Answer (score 0):

Put `pthreadGC2.dll` in a location where the `PATH` environment variable points to, or in the directory where the executable making use of it is located.